# Sent to my FTX wallet by mistake - Anyone know if I can get that back

Tags: sol

I sent some SOL to an (old) FTX wallet address by mistake.  The transaction completed and of course I can't login to FTX - Anyone any ideas how to go about getting that back?

Thanks,
Sol Down

Answer (score 3):

FTX is in receivership as part of bankruptcy proceedings. All of the FTX wallets are currently held as part of this. You've almost certainly burned these funds for good.

In the future, may I suggest:

- Sending a small amount of funds / tokens (e.g. 0.01 SOL) / whatever to the address before sending the main amount
- Verifying it on the explorer after sending the small amount of funds
- Verifying that the wallet address in the explorer is actually the address you want to send to

That way you only lose a small amount if you make a mistake. Good luck OP!